# Use Green's theorem to evaluate $\oint_c$ sketch the region R

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Given $\oint_c \tan^{-1}(x)dx + 3xdy $ and C is a rectangle with vertices $(1,0),(0,1),(2,3),(3,2).$
Here is what I have so far :
$$\oint_c \tan^{-1}(x)dx + 3xdy = \int\int_R (\frac{dn}{dx}-\frac{dm}{dy})$$
$$ M(x,y) = \tan^{-1}(x), \space N(x,y)=3x$$
$$\oint_c \tan^{-1}(x)dx + 3xdy = \int\int_R\ (\frac{d}{dx}(3x) - \frac{d}{dy}\tan^{-1}(x) dydx ) $$
$$= \int_0^3\int_0^3 (3 - 0)dydx$$
$$=\int_0^3 3y \vert_0^3 \space dx$$
$$=\int_0^3 9 \space dx$$
$$=\int_0^3 9x \vert_0^3 \space dx$$
$$= 27$$

How would I sketch this and is this the correct way to evaluate this line integral using Green's theroem ?

Comment: you already used the region in your calculation Isnt a square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region is $[0,3] \times [0,3]$, the region that you used in your integration.